# Core Data isn't being reset when I close the calling class - how can I reset it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

This is a question that appears to have been answered many times on Stack Overflow - but still it doesn't work for my use-case.  Core Data *mostly* works fine.  The problem comes when closing the document - at that point I need the Core Data to be reset, ready for the next Document to be loaded. What actually happens is that the next Document to be loaded gets loaded with all of its data, and all of the previous Documents data - and it doesn't reset until the Application is quit and reopened again.

I have an NSDocument based application which can load many different document types.  Each document type is described in its own Class.  **Foo**, for example, might be a really simple document type, small, text based, no problem to handle so it doesn't need a complex class to load it.  **Bar**, on the other hand, is a vast complicated database many GB in size - and it doesn't make sense to load it all into memory.

My Bar class uses Core Data - it's the only one that needs to, and therefore the only one which contains this logic. I mention this because nearly every description on how to use Core Data puts the Core Data code in App Delegate - there might be a good reason for this!

In my Bar header I have my Core Data set up as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSDate *readStart;
```

And in my Bar .m I have the following:

```
- (NSURL *)dataStoreURL {
    NSString *docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    //NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.sql",[StringWangers generateUUIDString]];
    NSString* filename = @"datastore.sql";
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    
    [NSFileManager.defaultManager removeItemAtURL:self.dataStoreURL error:nil]; // this isn't supposed to be persistent - clear out old crap
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @(YES), NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @(YES)};
    
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.alloc initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:self.dataStoreURL
                                                         options:options
                                                           error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved Core Data error with persistentStoreCoordinator: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    
    if ([self persistentStoreCoordinator]) {
        _managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext.alloc initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    }
    
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

I've tried many things to delete this pesky data - including, belt and braces, everything (which I really don't like doing because I'd like to understand what's going on - but I was desperate!) - this is the 'everything' state…

```
-(void)deinitialise {
    @try {
        NSLog(@"Deleting old core storage");
        NSArray *allEntities = self.managedObjectModel.entities;
        for (NSEntityDescription *entityDescription in allEntities) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest.new;
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
            fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
            fetchRequest.includesSubentities = NO;

            NSLog(@"%@",fetchRequest);

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *items;
            if (self.managedObjectContext &&
                fetchRequest &&
                ([fetchRequest.sortDescriptors isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] && fetchRequest.sortDescriptors.count > 0) &&
                fetchRequest.predicate) {
                items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
            }

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error requesting items from Core Data: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }

            for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
                [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
                [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error deleting items from Core Data: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting persistent storage - Exception: %@", exception);
    }
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray* persistentStoreArray = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores;
    for (id store in persistentStoreArray) {
        [self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error Removing Persistent Store: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        NSString* storePath = [store URL].path;
        NSLog(@"%@",storePath);
        [NSFileManager.defaultManager removeItemAtPath:storePath error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error Deleting Persistent Store: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
}
```

Interestingly, `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator` only gets called the first time that my **Bar** class is called on document load, but every time I call my reinitialise class.

Hopefully this makes sense to someone - 'cos I'm bang out of ideas.

Comment: Nearly every description on how to use Core Data is for iOS and `NSPersistentDocument` isn't available on iOS. `NSPersistentDocument` does not put the Core Data code in App Delegate. Create a Xcode project, macOS Cocoa app, document-based, Uses Core Data and take a look.

Comment: Can you please clarify, when you close a document, you want to delete all of the data from the user's Mac, not just get it out of memory? So that there is no possibility of loading that data again? I didn't think that was what you wanted, but since you're using `deleteObject` like that it seems that maybe it is.

Comment: I'd settle for getting it out of memory right now - but you're right, what I really want is to remove it altogether (which is why I also tried removeItemAtPath)

Comment: …Also, this is on Mac - not on iOS.

Comment: Can the app open two `Bar`s at the same time? Why don't you use `NSPersistentDocument`?

Comment: Yes - two Bars could be open at the same time, with different data. I'm not using NSPersistentDocument because the document isn't necessarily Core Data based. This is just one use case. In any event, this doesn't explain why my code isn't working… does it?

Comment: In the deinitialise code, your if condition includes fetchRequest.predicate, but you never set a predicate: so the fetchRequest is never executed.  As to the FileManager operation, have you checked the error?  And more broadly, you might need to delete the .sqlite-wal and -shm files as well (or use [destroyPersistentStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468888-destroypersistentstore)).

Comment: You should check the result of `removePersistentStore:error:`, `removeItemAtURL:error:` and other methods. Is the `Bar` file the dataStore file, does each `Bar` file have its own temporary dataStore file or do all `Bar`s share one dataStore file? From where do you call `deinitialise`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who posted suggestions.  They were great avenues of investigation - but they all turned out to be incorrect for my particular use-case. In the event, all I had to do was this:

```
-(void)deinitialise {
    [self.managedObjectContext reset];
}
```

I hope that this might help someone else who has this problem.